# On-prem AD server to manage Azure VMs and other on-prem machines?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-vm

I'm looking for a solution and to know if it's possible to have one (1) on-prem AD server to manage/authenticate Azure VMs and other on-prem servers (Hybrid infra). I've made some searching and I can only find the other way around where: Azure AD to authenticate on-prem and VMs **aka** hybrid Azure AD join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join a windows server machine to Azure Active Domain services. You can get more detailed explanation by checking in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm).

Hybrid Azure AD join is you can join your machine to both on-premises Active Directory and Azure Active Directory.  Azure Active Directory and Azure Active Directory Domain services are 2 different thigs.